# What does it mean when a manuscript submission systems lists the status of a paper as "Archived"?

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper in journal. After one day status is Archived. What is meaning of it? I did't get any communication information. Thanks.

Comment: My first guess about the meaning of "archived" would be that the existence of your paper has been recorded in the journal's database, but nothing else has been done with it.

Comment: Ok ..... It means it will consider late on ?? Thanks ....

Comment: @Andreas Blass i mailed to editor but no reply even after 5 days. Now what can I do?

Comment: My best guess is that the editor is unavailable at the moment --- sick or traveling or on vacation or ... --- so the journal's administrative staff is just holding on to the paper until the editor returns.

Comment: It is frustrating. It has also happened to me. There is no communication from the journal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on what system the journal is using, what processes the editors are following, what that editor in question was thinking that day, and maybe other factors.

Point being that there is no way for you -- or in fact, anyone -- to know for sure. You have two choices:

- Ask the editor.
- Have patience.

I would suggest the second. You will get a notification in due time when someone has made a decision. You can also look up what turn-around time the journal strives for (say, 3 months) and then round about that time email the editor if you haven't heard back until then. But after just a single day, the only reasonable answer is: Have patience!

Comment: I mailed to editor but no reply even after 5 days. Now what can I do?

Comment: Now what? Go to step 2: have patience.  If there is no change after a month, then take further action.